# how to use positional argument from argparse.Namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, python-multithreading, argparse

I am trying to build a cli and wxpython gui application in two files.
The wx app calls the cli app for functionalites.
When I wrap my arguments in the wx app to a Namespace it does not get accepted from the cli app.
`window.py: error: the following arguments are required: filepath`

I simplified the files to show only the related parts:

window.py

```
import os
from argparse import Namespace
from threading import Thread
from main import main

def window():
    try:
        print('window try')
        args = Namespace(
                        filepath = os.getcwd()+'file.xy',
                        outputpath =  os.getcwd()
                        )
        thread = Thread(target=main, args=(args,))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error:{e}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     window()
```

main.py

```
import os
import argparse


def main(*args):
    print(f'START main args:{args}, type of args:{type(args)}')
    if args:
        args=args[0]
    print(f'tuple0:{args}, type of args:{type(args)}')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filepath', default=os.getcwd())
    parser.add_argument('-o', dest='outputpath')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(f'DONE main args:{args}, type of args:{type(args)}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
➜  argparse python3 main.py ~/Documents/
START main args:(), type of args:<class 'tuple'>
tuple0:(), type of args:<class 'tuple'>
DONE main args:Namespace(filepath='/Users/novski/Documents/', outputpath=None), type of args:<class 'argparse.Namespace'>
➜  argparse python3 window.py      
window try
START main args:(Namespace(filepath='/Users/novski/Documents/argparse/file.xy', outputpath='/Users/novski/Documents/argparse'),), type of args:<class 'tuple'>
tuple0:Namespace(filepath='/Users/novski/Documents/argparse/file.xy', outputpath='/Users/novski/Documents/argparse'), type of args:<class 'argparse.Namespace'>
usage: window.py [-h] [-o OUTPUTPATH] filepath
window.py: error: the following arguments are required: filepath
```

Why does `Namespace(filepath...` doesn't get accepted as `filepath` when i hand it over through `args` from my window.py to main.py?

Is there a better solution, how to use my cli app (main.py) from the GUI (window.py)?

Comment: `parser.parse_args()` parses `sys.argv`.  The fact that you  already have a variable called `args` doesn't change that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running the parser conditionally?

```
if args:
    args=args[0]
    print(f'tuple0:{args}, type of args:{type(args)}')
else:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filepath', default=os.getcwd())
    parser.add_argument('-o', dest='outputpath')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the list of strings you want the parser to parse, not the object it might ultimately return.

```
def window():
    try:
        print('window try')
        args = ['-o', os.getcwd(), os.getcwd() + 'file.xy']
        thread = Thread(target=main, args=(args,))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error:{e}')
```

and

```
# Parse args will parse whatever list main() receives, or sys.argv[1:]
# if nothing is given to main().
def main(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filepath', default=os.getcwd())
    parser.add_argument('-o', dest='outputpath')
    args = parser.parse_args(args)
    print(f'DONE main args:{args}, type of args:{type(args)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: argparse - Parser for command-line options, arguments and sub-command](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

I fixed the errors in your code:

- Pass the arguments received by *main* to *parse_args* (instead of relying on *sys.argv*)
- Remove `if args: args = args[0]` (don't know what it's for, and it's just ugly (looks like working around a bug))
- Give up *Namespace* (as default one is more than enough)
- Pass the arguments to *main* as a sequence (exemplified many times in the (above) *URL*)
- Also change the parsing options to (what I consider to be) a user friendlier form

Demo:

- *main.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import argparse
  import os
  import sys


  def main(*argv):
      print(f"Start main: {argv}")
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument("--filepath", "-f", default=os.getcwd())
      parser.add_argument("--outputpath", "-o",)
      parsed_args = parser.parse_args(args=argv)
      print(f"Parsed arguments: {parsed_args}")


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```
- *window.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import os
  import sys
  from threading import Thread

  from main import main


  def window():
      try:
          print("Start wwindow")
          args = ("-f", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "file.py"), "-o", os.getcwd())
          thread = Thread(target=main, args=args)
          thread.start()
          thread.join()
      except Exception as e:
          print(f"Exception: {e}")


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = window()
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q075373104]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./main.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Start main: ()
> Parsed arguments: Namespace(filepath='e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q075373104', outputpath=None)
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./main.py -f file
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Start main: ('-f', 'file')
> Parsed arguments: Namespace(filepath='file', outputpath=None)
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./main.py -f file -o dir
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Start main: ('-f', 'file', '-o', 'dir')
> Parsed arguments: Namespace(filepath='file', outputpath='dir')
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./window.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Start wwindow
> Start main: ('-f', 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q075373104\\file.py', '-o', 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q075373104')
> Parsed arguments: Namespace(filepath='e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q075373104\\file.py', outputpath='e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q075373104')
>
> Done.
> ```